# Why is my environment variable not recognized after Cloud Run deploy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

My node application needs an environment variable as requirement to make a POST request. Everything works fine in my local machine by accessing the `.env` file content directly. I also did make sure to set `${_TM_API_KEY}` in GCP so I can trigger it, as suggested by the docs, however it doesn't seem to recognize the variable after the application is deployed. What am I doing wrong? Any further suggestion would be deeply appreciated it. My cloudbuild.yaml looks like this:

```
steps:
  - id: build
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      [
        "build",
        "-t",
        "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/suweb:${SHORT_SHA}",
        "--build-arg=ENV=${_TM_API_KEY}",
        ".",
      ]
    env:
      - "TM_API_KEY=${_TM_API_KEY}"

  - id: push
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/suweb:${SHORT_SHA}"]

  - id: deploy
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args:
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      - "suweb"
      - "--set-env-vars=TM_API_KEY=${_TM_API_KEY}"
      - "--image"
      - "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/suweb:${SHORT_SHA}"
      - "--region"
      - "us-central1"
      - "--platform"
      - "managed"
      - "--allow-unauthenticated"

images:
  - "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/suweb:${SHORT_SHA}"
```

More details: the code where the API_KEY is being referenced is in the following header:

```
const headers = {
  TM_API_KEY: process.env.TM_API_KEY,
  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
};
```

And my `.env` file looks like this:

```
TM_API_KEY=_TM_API_KEY
```

It is a bit unclear for me if I should reference the trigger variable here as well (_TM_API_KEY) or write the key value.

After that, when doing a form post request, the server responds with a CORS policy error telling that such endpoint couldn't be reached. I tried by hard coding the API_KEY in the headers and everything works fine, no errors whatsoever.

Comment: Where are you referencing the environment variable? Show the code, errors, debugging steps, etc.

Comment: Please include the deployed Cloud Run YAML so that we may see what results. It's curious that you're applying `${_TM_API_KEY}` both to the container build as a `build-arg` and at runtime. Trying to think through why both would be needed.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just added more details. Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Comment: @DazWilkin I will ask my supervisor for the deployed YAML tomorrow morning since unfortunately I don't have permissions to access to the Cloud Run! But I just added more details. It is unclear for me whether to apply the environment variable in build or runtime. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: You'll need to ensure that you're providing a value for `_TM_API_KEY` to Cloud Build when you trigger the build. I *suspect* you're not passing a value and getting an empty (`""`) value. You can confirm this by inspecting the service's YAML

Comment: Sorry for that out of purpose comment, but shouldn't be better to store an API KEY in a secret instead of in plain text in an environment variable?